# Getting PayPal Test Account Profile

Tags: testing, paypal, token, profile, account

All I want to do is get the credentials from my test account to see the Profile to make test payments on my online store.
The old Sandbox worked like the Live page and I used to easily get my test profile. The new sandbox interface make it all different.
I was able to login to sandbox with my LIVE business account, then import my old test accounts (business and personal).

But how do I get the test business account Profile? How to log in with a test account?

All I see is this on the new sandbox:
[image: New Interface]

***What I need is to get is this on the new sandbox interface:***

***Merchant ID***

[image: Mechant ID]

***And the Return URL and Identity Token:***

[image: url & token]

After I get this info from the Test Business account, I can continue with developing and running in a test environment.  I think the live settings are still working, but don't want to check yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on 'Sandbox site' instead of 'Profile' you'll be redirected to the Sandbox page where you can login to the account and access the information you're looking for.
Alternatively, simply navigate to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/home which would be the exact same page.

Comment: Thanks for the post!  Ok, this is what happens.  I enter https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/home.  I see this:  http://www.atmcomm.com/imagebucket/paypal6.jpg.   Somehow the site automatically logged me in using my LIVE business account.   Then I enter a test business username & password.  I get in and it looks like this: http://www.atmcomm.com/imagebucket/paypal4.jpg.  Great! Now I click on Profile: and I get this Error: http://www.atmcomm.com/imagebucket/paypal5.jpg.  Then I try to log out.  I see this 503 Error: http://www.atmcomm.com/imagebucket/paypal7.jpg  What else can I do?

Comment: One more thing. If I do click on 'Sandbox site' instead of 'Profile'. I get this 404 error: http://www.atmcomm.com/imagebucket/paypal8.jpg.  Another time I got this: http://www.atmcomm.com/imagebucket/paypal9.jpg

Comment: I have the same experience and posted a similar request for help. PayPal_Robert replied but I see no resolution yet. Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343534/i-can-log-on-to-the-paypal-sandbox-test-account-but-can-not-get-into-profile-or