# I can log on to the PayPal Sandbox test account but can not get into Profile or Settings

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I was unable to log on to my PayPal developer account until I deleted the PayPal cookies from Chrome. This allowed me to log on but clicking on Profile or Settings within the Profile drop-down results in an error page saying "Please login to use the PayPal Sandbox features".

Logging in again did not help. Creating a new account (buyer or seller) did not help either.

This is in the new Sandbox environment.

Answer (score 3):

Strange as it may seem, deleting your developer.paypal.com should resolve this.
The reason for this is that you've got cookies from the old developer portal in place which interferes with the new portal / sandbox environment.
After you've deleted all your cookies / all your paypal.com cookies, you should be able to login to the new developer portal and access any sandbox accounts without any issue.

A fix for this is going out shortly.

Comment: Well deleting my PayPal cookies did allow me to log on to my test accounts. However, I can't get into any of my test accounts' Profile page.

Comment: That's odd. Can you reproduce this in an incognito session as well? Are these new accounts you created, or existing accounts you imported? Do you have the Sandbox (not developer portal) email address of one of these accounts for me?

Comment: I tried incognito in Chrome and it still displayed "Please login..." when clicking the Profile link for the test account. This happened both to an old imported test account and a newly created test account. I recently emailed details to you, Robert.

Comment: I have the details as well GarDavis, I'll be looking into this further and will be in touch soon. Thank you for sending the details.

Comment: @ GarDavis. I sent you an email with some more details. I'm still looking into this now and hope yo have more information for you soon.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is still having problems accessing their My Profile (other than My business info) in the sandbox (i only get the perpetual loading animation) - then just use this link:

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_classic-profile-summary

Comment: Great workaround. Just to clarify - once you've got that link, you can adjust all the settings through the links at the bottom of the page, **not** through the menu.

Comment: yes, that's correct... and the menu is **still** not working for me

Answer (score 1):

Paypal sandbox is generally broken for everyone, seeing a lot of people complaining about it. It was ropey at best before, seems to have truly died now.

Comment: Couple of hiccups that we didn't see in testing with regards to the new developer portal. Shouldn't have happened and rest assured we will address. Happy to work directly with you on tackling any other Sandbox / Developer Portal issues that you might have though - contact details are in my profile. Thanks!

Comment: how paypal is buggy on its live servers. really worse things