# sandbox test account login going to old, broken site

Tags: paypal-sandbox

I have been unable to log in to the new sandbox site with any of my test accounts, I keep getting sent to the old sandbox site, which is too broken to use.

I followed the advice given in this response: [I can log on to the PayPal Sandbox test account but can not get into Profile or Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343534) but deleting the "sandbox.paypal" cookies and emptying the cache hasn't prevented the login to the test account going to the old sandbox site.

I've tried closing the browser and starting over, but I still get sent to the old site when I log in to a test account.

This is pretty much preventing any testing from happening, as I need to test it with different account settings, and I can't access them.

Answer (score 0):

The sandbox URL or sandbox accounts themselves did not change to a newer one.  Only the developer account.  So you should still be going to the same sandbox account and login pages for these accounts.

What happens when you try accessing the pages you are wanting to navigate to?  Are you being sent to the live site, or are you getting an error?  What specific page/settings are you trying to access within your sandbox account?

Comment: OK, when I am in the developer site, I go to Applications/Sandbox accounts, then click on the "Sandbox site" link under the test account I want to administer. This takes me to the sandbox version of the PP home page. At the top, there's a login, where I login to the test account.

At this point, it takes me to the old sandbox site, where it is impossible to edit the account's selling preferences unser Profile/My Settings. If you click on that link you just get an endlessly spinning gif where the settings should be.

Comment: It has happened once or twice that I can get to the new sandbox site, and that works great...until the account automatically logs out after a while, and then when I log in again, I am stuck on the old sandbox site again.

I have not found a way to consistently access the new sandbox site, I would love to leran how.

All the while, I remain logged in to my main (real) PayPal account.

Comment: Can you open up a ticket with PayPal Merchant Technical Support at www.paypal.com/mts and provide the sandbox email address that you are trying to access, the steps you are following and any screenshots that you can so that we can look into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same problem.
I log in, it tells me "Please login to use Sandbox features". I get redirected back to the developer site in which I am already logged in.

Comment: Actually, what's happening for me is I get logged in, but to the old sandbox site.

Comment: You can see my comment below...your experience seems quite different. Have you tried clearing your PayPal cookies?